# Basic use of .env files to store API keys

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, environment-variables

I've recently been working with GitHub on web-apps that require hard-coded passwords in a JS file. One solution to this I just learned about was securing these using an .env file. However, I've never used an .env file before, and am not even quite sure HOW they can be used.

Some links that I've found that sort of touch upon this is https://jordancotter.wordpress.com/2018/12/11/using-environment-variables-with-vanilla-javascript/. What I'm really looking for is if it is possible to
a) use .env files completely client-side (Vanilla JS or Jquery)
and 
b) store variables inside of this which can be SAFELY called in my index.html file via the `<script src="ENV FILE"></script>` way.

To be more specific, I'd like to know if there is some way to turn `var password="PASS"` into a secure variable which can be accessed by the program and is not so vulnerable.

Is this possible? If yes, then how? Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely nothing you send to the client is secure.

Comment: Store anything sensitive on a server. If you need to access a remote API with those keys for example you make request to your server and have it make the remote request with credentials and return that response to client. Lots of resources around for quickly setting up a cloud server

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your quick response! I was wondering more about a completely client-side solution, but will definitely look into your idea! Part of the reason I wanted it to be client side is that it is a downloadable software from GitHub that anyone can run, so ideally a set-up on my end that could be downloaded and automatically secure would be best. When I heard about .env files, I imagined something where I could "pop in a JS variable, and have output a string that automatically calls the file to where it is not hard-codeed anywhere visible to the user."

Comment: Well if it's only client-side, there is no way to keep your key secure, so use a backend like PHP, flask, or Django so the user can't see the code while you can access GitHub API.

Comment: @charlietfl - where do you securely store the credentials to make the request to get the api key (or make a request on your behalf using the api key)?

Comment: @Adam Store them server side where they aren't exposed to public. Server then uses them to do a remote authenticated request

Comment: @charlietfl - I misunderstood. I thought you said you should make a request to your server using credentials.

Comment: "I've recently been working with GitHub on web-apps that require hard-coded passwords in a JS file." no they don't. Explain _that_ part of your codebase, because this is almost certainly not true.

Comment: Ok, I'll attempt to answer all of the above comments with one of my own. I'm storing the passwords inside my gitsaver.js file on my repo, which makes various Get requests to the GitHub Tree API with the Basic Authentication method. While the key encoded is my PAT with only read/write permission, I'd feel better without this available at all. In addition to this, the whole point of the repo is to accomplish certain tasks (i.e. updating wiki) without a server, which it does (except for the API key)